# php-How to get logged-in user's different data by their ID From database

Tags: php

actually i am trying to fetch the logged-in user's data in the data table. Actually they are alloted to orders and i am trying to fetch their data as an employee(user) from database..
So, its like that , when a user logged in , system should display just the logged-in user's data...
it's showing the sum of row from Database ,and it's working here for different data for different user....

```php
$result= mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT SUM(paid) AS totalsum FROM orders WHERE employee_id='".$_SESSION['user']['user_id']."'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

$sum = $row['totalsum'];
```

But it's not fetching the logged-in user's data.(the data where these logged-in users are allocated as an employee and they have to see their record to take actions )

```php
$sql = "SELECT order_id, order_date, client_name,client_contact,payment_status,client_address,mac_address,client_address2,series,user_status,connection_type FROM orders WHERE order_status = 1 AND employee_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."' ";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

$sql = "SELECT order_id, order_date, client_name,client_contact,payment_status,client_address,mac_address,client_address2,series,user_status,connection_type FROM orders WHERE order_status = 1 AND employee_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."' ";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

$sql = "SELECT order_id, order_date, client_name,client_contact,payment_status,client_address,mac_address,client_address2,series,user_status,connection_type FROM orders WHERE order_status = 1 AND employee_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."' ";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
```

DataTables are showing this error

> DataTables warning: table id=manageOrderTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: If this works `employee_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."' "` and this does not `WHERE employee_id='".$_SESSION['user']['user_id']."'"` Do you see the diffeerence

Comment: sorry i think it was deleted somehow but i am using this 
employee_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."' and even with that it's not showing the data and showing DataTable error 
I am unable to undersatnd that why its not showing the data with this $_SESSION code while it is showing above additon of rows data .

Comment: i think its creating ambiguity ..
Above code is working with $_SESSIOn and showing different data for different users.
But below code is not working with SAME WHERE Condition

Comment: Its a little odd keeping all the client data in an Order record!

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Sorry but its not showing any errors ... 
Dear , i think we should concentrate on this why its not getting the different data for different users while it is doing addition likewise ?

Comment: If you are getting an error `Invalid JSON response` then please show us where you generate a JSON string and send it to the browser

Comment: Do you run these 3 queries in your code jus like this? Where is the code that processes the resultsets from these queries

Comment: there is an issue of session_start() 
Solved ! thank you so much for your response

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just have to start the session again in my file session_start(); it started fetching the data differently for different users! 
Cuz it was directing the main page to JSON file and then to fetch file! that's why the session was giving an error ! 
Thank you ALL

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve so by setting session variables after user logs in successfully you can simply set session variable to user id/email of user.

To know more please see this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your response Dear .But it's not getting the job done ... I have tried setting evrything ,changed condition so i can successfully show the logged user's data but stuck ..
And i have used employee_id='".$_SESSION['user']['user_id']."' ...so ? 
What's wrong with it

Comment: Situation is : 
I have orders form ,where admin allocated the order to employee 
And in order table there is employee_id , and in users table ,username,user_id,user_type 
I have to calculate the paid price of order for every usery differently ,
I have done so with the same code 
But where i have to fetch the data of each user differently 
Its not working ?